# Validate null value throwing undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0"
        ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected"
        ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos ">
</select>
```

From there I get `selected value` in function like this:

```
$scope.filtro = function(selected) {
            $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
        }
```

There I get `Id` for `selected value`, but now I use it into another function, but that function can get parameter null or not  so function is:

```
$scope.insertar = function () {
            if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {
                    var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo;

                    if ($scope.selected.ID != null) {
                        url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
                    }
                apiService.post(url....
```

Problem is when it comes null it just throw `$scope.selected is undefined` when it pass this validation

```
                 if ($scope.selected.ID != null) {
                            url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
                        }
```

How can I validate it if `$scope.selected` doesn´t exist in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you stored it in `$scope.selectedID` but retrieving from `$scope.selected.ID`.

Use

```
if ($scope.selectedID != null) {
```